# Liquibase:diff - Unsupported property type for generator annotation @CreationTimestamp on ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jhipster, liquibase

I have an Entity with a `ZonedDateTime` filed annotated with `@CreationTimestamp`:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created")
private ZonedDateTime created;
```

When running:

```
mvn liquibase:diff
```

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.5:diff (default-cli) on project myproject: Error setting up or running Liquibase: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unsupported property type for generator annotation @CreationTimestamp -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here my hibernate and liquibase dependencies in the **pom.xml**:

```
<!-- The hibernate version should match the one managed by
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
<hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>

<!-- The liquibase version should match the one managed by
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
<liquibase.version>3.5.5</liquibase.version>
<liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
```

What are the correct versions to use for the @CreationTimeStamp to work on a ZonedDateTime field?

Comment: The only workaround I found was to simply remove the annotation before running the liquibase:diff command, then put it back.
Is still not supported the ZonedDateTime, even with hibernate 5.4.0.final ?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that can be with the object setters:

```
public void setDateCreated(Object object) {
        if (object.getId() == null) {
            // which will run only when the object is new
            this.dateCreated = Instant.now();
        }
    }
public void setDateUpdated() {
        // which runs everytime the object is updated
        this.dateUpdated = Instant.now();
    }
```

Or you can manually set the valueDate attribute on your liquibase changelog before running your change diff:

```
<column name="Join_date" valueDate="${now}"/>
```

Or comment out the annotations when running the liquibase diff and add them back when you're done.